# Understanding this Rust borrow/pointer example

Tags: rust

I'm reading https://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/04/10/Fearless-Concurrency.html, and there's this example about borrowing:

> Why have two kinds of references? Consider a function like:
>
> ```
> fn push_all(from: &Vec<i32>, to: &mut Vec<i32>) {
>     for i in from.iter() {
>         to.push(*i);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This function iterates over each element of one vector, pushing it
>   onto another. The iterator keeps a pointer into the vector at the
>   current and final positions, stepping one toward the other.
>
> What if we called this function with the same vector for both
>   arguments?
>
> ```
> push_all(&vec, &mut vec)
> ```
>
> This would spell disaster! As we're pushing elements onto the vector,
>   it will occasionally need to resize, allocating a new hunk of memory
>   and copying its elements over to it. The iterator would be left with a
>   dangling pointer into the old memory, leading to memory unsafety (with
>   attendant segfaults or worse).

I didn't understand the dangling pointer. I also don't understand what `*i` means in Rust. I guess it's pointer deferencing. But why `for` iterates over raw pointers? And how does `push(*i)` work? It copies? How do I know when Rust copies, borrows or owns?

Comment: Iterators in Rust are like iterators in C++. They are essentially raw pointers into memory. When you have an iterator into a vector, and need to grow that vector, the iterator becomes invalid. That's true for Rust as well as C++. The only difference is: A C++ compiler will happily support you in exploring the vast space of undefined behavior that ensues.

Comment: @IInspectable I can picture (I think) an implementation of std::vector that can grow but still leave all the old elements in the same place. Do you mean that `std::vector` grows, then copies the old elements to a new place? That's why the iterator points to invalid data?

Comment: Just like a vector in Rust, a vector in C++ is required to store its controlled sequence in a continuous block of memory. There is no practical implementation of a vector in either language where appending elements is guaranteed to never invalidate iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't understand the dangling pointer.

A vector is backed by a buffer with a certain capacity. When you add a new item to the vector, if the backing array is full it needs to "make more room".

The way it does this is by creating a new array bigger than the old one (usually by some factor e.g. 1.6 or 2), moving all the contents over to the new buffer, then destroying the old buffer.

But if you could use the same vector for iteration and addition, in this case the iterator *would still point to the destroyed buffer*, which is what "dangling" means in this case: the pointer would "dangle" because it'd be a valid pointer (as opposed to a null pointer) to unallocated memory.

> I also don't understand what *i means in Rust. I guess it's pointer deferencing. But why for iterates over raw pointers?

`for` iterates over an iterator over a Vec, which is really [an iterator over a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html). Now iterators have an `Item` associated type, which is the type of the things they yield when iterating. For the iterator above,

```
type Item = &'a T
```

This means `from.iter()` is an iterator which yields *references* to the items in the vec, `&i32` in this case. If you want an `i32` from an `&i32`, you have to dereference the reference, hence `*i`.

> And how does push(*i) work?

The normal way?

> It copies? How do I know when Rust copies, ~~borrows or~~ owns?

Depends on the type of the vector (and parameter as they ought match). Here `i32` is Copy, so it copies.

At runtime that doesn't really make any difference (save for some optimisations), copy and move (what I guess you mean by own) are the same operation, the difference is whether you can still use the "source" afterwards.

> How do I know when Rust borrows

IIRC Rust can borrow in two cases:

- if you tell it to using `&` or `&mut`
- if you call a method (depending whether the method takes `&self`, `&mut self` or `self`, the latter is a move or copy, the other two are borrows)

So that's how you know when rust borrows. Or copies/moves.

Comment: "Here i32 is Copy, so it copies.". Can you clarify on this part?

Comment: There's really not much to clarify: by default Rust types are moved, but they can be opted-into [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), which changes this. [That's the case for `i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-19).

Comment: Thanks I needed to know what Copy meant, now I'm gonna read how it works, it clarified a lot!